# Homomorphisms and tensor product concerning $\mathrm{Hom}(L, M \otimes N)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

I have a question regarding $\mathrm{Hom}(L, M \otimes N)$, where $L,M,N$ are $A$-modules over a commutative ring $A$.
I know, that 
$$\mathrm{Hom}_A(M \otimes_A N, L) \cong 
  \mathrm{Hom}_A(M, \mathrm{Hom}_A(N,L))$$

Is there an analogue for $\mathrm{Hom}(L, M \otimes N)$? Something like
$$\mathrm{Hom}(L, M \otimes N) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(\mathrm{Hom}(L,M), N)$$
I know the proof cannot be analogue, as the first isomorphism is given by the isomorphism between 
$\mathrm{Bil}(M \times N,L) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(M, \mathrm{Hom}(N,L))$ and you can obviously not speak of $\mathrm{Bil}(L, M \times N)$.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The precise question could be: does the functor $F : M \mapsto M \otimes_A N$ have a left adjoint (i.e. is it a right adjoint of some other functor)? It doesn't, because a right adjoint [is left exact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338833), and $F$ is not left exact (unless $N$ is a flat $A$-module).

---

Further details: a functor $F : \mathsf{Mod}_A \to \mathsf{Mod}_A$ is a right adjoint if there is a functor $G : \mathsf{Mod}_A \to \mathsf{Mod}_A$ such that there are natural bijections
$$\mathrm{Hom}_A(G(L), M) = \mathrm{Hom}_A(L, F(M)).$$

---

However, you might be interested by the following related question: [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1728363/is-it-true-that-operatornamehom-rm-n-otimes-r-p-operatornamehom-rm-n).

Comment: nice and elegant answer, thanks!

Comment: The functor $F$ might have a left adjoint in some cases. We saw that flatness of $N$ is necessary. If $N$ is a free module of finite rank, then $F$ has a left adjoint, namely $F$ itself (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2538181/direct-sum-and-hom)).

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1550458) tells you when $F$ has a left adjoint: exactly when $N$ is finitely generated and projective (if $A$ is a domain, this is the same as "finitely generated and flat"). 

In that case, the left adjoint of $F$ is $N^* \otimes_A -$, i.e. we have natural bijections
$$ \mathrm{Hom}_A(N^* \otimes_A X, Y) \cong  \mathrm{Hom}_A(X, Y \otimes_A N).$$

Comment: In the above bijections are deduced from $$\mathrm{Hom}_A(N^* \otimes_A X, Y) \cong \mathrm{Hom}_A(X, \mathrm{Hom}_A(N^*, Y)) \cong \mathrm{Hom}_A(X, N \otimes_A Y),$$ using [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1988633/) and the fact that $N$ is finitely generated projective.